# Round only Inclusive price in magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, rounding

I have both price inclusive and exclusive tax on product listing and detail page. Now i want to round off only inclusive price on product listing and detail page. Exclusive price will be same as it. How can i round only inclusive price.

[image: I want only round incl price]

I want to round only Incl price to 151.00 €.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Updated.Please check.

Comment: In Stote>confifration>sales>Tax You can manage your Tax Like inclusive and exclusive.

Comment: I want to round inclusive price only. Both price are already displayed.

Comment: turn on the template path on and see which is the file and go there and add round function for inclu tex price.